# More than one trigger on a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Is it possible to create more than one trigger on the same table in mysql?
I want to create two triggers on the same table if possible.Below is what I have tried but it does not work.

First trigger on table labeled table1,

```sql
Create trigger update_table BEFORE INSERT ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.Academic_Year='2010'
```

Second trigger on table labeled table1,

```sql
Create trigger update_table BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.Fees='20.00'
```

The two above triggers work separately but do not work when they are together.Please any help is appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just combine them into one trigger? Although I would say that you should avoid triggers in most cases.

Comment: @George Can you elaborate on what you actually trying to achieve? You can't call triggers per se. They are being called by MySql in one of the events (in your case before insert) no matter how you make that insert by client code from one of your php pages, or by mysql client or by another trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your time.I actually want every row in the 'table1' to automatically posses the 'Fees' data thus '20.00' and 'Academic_Year' data thus '2010', after they are inserted into the table.The issue here is that the Academic_Year and Fees data are set from different pages by the user.Hope this is clear.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comments you need some sort of default table that you will use in your trigger and values in which can be changed by an administrator.

`defaults` table schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE defaults
(`id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
 `fees` decimal(12, 2) not null default 0, 
 `academic_year` int not null default 0, 
 `created` datetime not null
)
```

The idea is store all defaults along with a timestamp when they took effect. In order to change defaults just insert a new row with new defaults.

```sql
INSERT INTO Defaults (`fees`, `academic_year`, `created`)
VALUES (25.00, 2011, NOW())
```

Now the trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_table1
BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE _fees DECIMAL(12, 2);
  DECLARE _year INT;

  SELECT fees, academic_year 
    INTO _fees, _year
    FROM defaults
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 1;

   SET NEW.fees          = _fees, 
       NEW.academic_year = _year;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/685de/1)** demo

Comment: Hi peterm, please I want to have a chat with you,can you kindly schedule a time for us to talk...please is really important.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple triggers for the same action. But you can wrap everything between Begin and end:

```
DELIMITER $$
Create trigger update_table BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.Academic_Year='2010';
SET NEW.Fees='20.00';
END $$
```

Please notice you have to use DELIMITER.

One trigger leads to another and thinks may fast became messy. Triggers are hard to debug especially when they trigger each other. Just be sure you know what are you doing while writting triggers and procedures for your database.

Comment: Yea thanks but i want to actually call the triggers from two different pages in php, that is why i wanted to create the two triggers from the two different pages.thanks.

Comment: How do you want database to find out from which site comes your insert statement? You can't do this. Triggers are triggered during performed action (in this case before finishing insert statement). Even if you had two separated triggers they woud have been triggered in the same time. Maybe you shoud use procedures or functions?